# Want to calculate years, month, days from multiple dates in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular11

I have multiple date inputs by user for his job experience.
For example a user has experiences like

exp1 = 1st feb, 2015 to 1st feb, 2016
exp2 = 6th feb, 2016 to 28th march, 2020

Now i want to calculate years, months and days for both these dates.

How to acheive this in js. I tried with moment but couldnt do so.

Comment: please show us your attempt

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```js
function dateCalculator(date1,date2) {
    const diff = Math.floor(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
    const day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    const days = Math.floor(diff/day);
    const months = Math.floor(days/31);
    const years = Math.floor(months/12);

    const output = `Years: ${years}, Months: ${months}, Days: ${days}`;

    return output
    }

const firstDate = new Date();
const secondDate = new Date(2015, 2, 1);
const diff = dateCalculator(firstDate,secondDate)
console.log(diff)
```

However, the format of the dates you gave won't work with this method.